# box2d collision groups isn't sufficient for bullets from own player

Tags: javascript, box2d, collision

So I know about collision groups and filters, etc. But I need a way on the server to check if the bullet came from the same player. If this was just on the client that would be easy because I could create a collision group for player's own bullets and one for enemy bullets, but since the server is the one detecting the collisions there's no "client" player and every player and bullet is treated the same, other than the user data attached to the bullet has a uid.

So basically I want something like this -

```
  if(collisionA.m_userData.type == "projectile"){
            if(collisionA.m_userData.uid === collisionB.m_userData.uid){
               dontApplyCollisionOrPhysics()
            }
        }
```

Comment: still haven't found a solution

Answer (score 0):

You could improve your bullet object by adding a property owner

```
function bullet(owner){
    //Your Bullet properties
    this.owner = owner;
}
```

You only create the object bullet when you are going to use it, so in that moment you add the owner. In this case, the uid.

Comment: I get that, but how can I use that variable to prevent it from knocking back my player? the bullet spawns in the middle of the player